# How to count the quantity of objects in ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView set in my TabLayout, for each tab i just filter out items from the list in the RecyclerView and for each tab the user can chose X items from the RecyclerView and once that limit is reached the TabLayout will be set to the next tab.

My RecyclerView is based on a `ArrayList<ItemPTERM>` where ItemPTERM is an object which has `description` in it and `quantity`.

Once a new item has been chosen from the `RecyclerView` or it's quantity has been increased i have to check if the items limit is still valid else i have to skip to the next tab.

So i've made the following function to check so in my `Adapter`:

```
private boolean isQuantityValid() {
    int quantity = 0;
    for (final ItemPTERM item : piattiItems) {
        if (quantity > limit) {
            return false;
        }
        quantity += (int) item.getQuant();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which then is called in my `PlusMinusAdd` function. Is that the best way to count the quantity of added items?

Comment: What type does `item.getQuant()` actually return? You cast it to an `int` before summing the values up, that's why I'm asking...

Comment: @deHaar it's a double because in other cases where ItemPTERM is used it could have decimals but it's not that case.

Comment: So better have your accumulator be a `double` then. With 64bit processors, most working variables (as opposed to storage variables or in arrays) should be long and double anyway, as usually there's no advantage for using the shorter versions, only complications and limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you do is the best way to go. Simple, plain old Java.

IMO there's little to change:

- Run the check after you changed the value (first check won't do any good, and if the list by accident finishes with an invalid result you would still return true in your implementation)
- use a double for counting (because accumulated rounding errors might also get you into trouble; accept at most one final rounding error when comparing)
- maybe parameterize the limit (if it differs)
- introduce null check (ArrayList can hold null values)

Code:

```
private boolean isQuantityValid(double pLimit) {
    double quantity = 0;
    for (final ItemPTERM item : piattiItems) {
        if (item == null) continue;
        quantity += item.getQuant();
        if (quantity > pLimit) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

There's another possibility of using streams, but that's just more complicated and slower, unless you have immense (1'000'000 +) amounts of entries in your list, where automatic parallelization would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

An other way to count the total quantity of the items can be done with `stream`, `map` and `reduce`.

Example how the total quantity is calculated with these:

```java
int quantity = piattiItems.stream()
    .map(item -> (int) item.getQuant())
    .reduce(0, (q, i) -> q+i);
```

Your method then could look like this:

```java
private boolean isQuantityValid() {
  int quantity = piattiItems.stream()
      .map(item -> (int) item.getQuant())
      .reduce(0, (q, i) -> q + i);

  return quantity > limit ? false : true;
}
```

If you want to filter some objects (e.g. `null`) you can just add a filter to the stream like this:

```java
int quantity = piattiItems.stream()
    .filter(item -> item != null)
    .map(item -> (int) item.getQuant())
    .reduce(0, (q, i) -> q+i);
```

With this the method gets much more compact and (in my opinion) easier to read.

Comment: Nicely done. This is the exact counterpart written in streams ;-) (although the int rounding errors might play a role here)

Comment: Oh hey, another question: in my example above we return early if the quantity get too high. Do you know how one could incorporate that into the streams solution too? To be honest, I have no clue how I could model that in an easy way... maybe you do. Maybe I learn something from this (almost off-topic) side-question :-D

Comment: Thats a good question. I have to admit, that I have never thought about it. The first that would come to my mind is to throw a RunTimeException inside of the BinaryFunction where the summation is done and surround the whole thing with a try-catch block. But this does not sound very optimal :). Maybe there is a possibility with `takeWhile`, which was introduced in Java 9.